# Python Opencv images

Tags: python, opencv

```
def Read_img(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    WIDTH = 500
    RATIO = WIDTH / float(w)
    HEIGHT = int(h * RATIO) + 50
    return cv2.resize(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

for names in os.listdir(known_faces_dir):
    print(names)

for file_name in os.listdir(f'{known_faces_dir}/{names}'):
    print(file_name)
    image = Read_img(f'{known_faces_dir}/{names}')
```

Here is the code my Read_img function is the problem it returns an error when i run the image variable

here is the error

```
File "Facial_Rec.py", line 23, in <module>
image = Read_img(f'{known_faces_dir}/{names}')
File "Facial_Rec.py", line 12, in Read_img`enter code here`
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read a folder as an image. Try `image = Read_img(f'{known_faces_dir}/{names}/{file_name}')`.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to open an image but the path is not correct, OpenCV does not tell you that it could not find the image, it returns None. So when you want to check the shape you get an error

Answer (score 0):

if the type is None just continue and pass to the next loop

```
if type(img) is None:
    continue
```